# MySql Trigger Syntax to lookup a value in a table and update in the updated row

Tags: mysql, triggers, syntax-error

I'm converting some old legacy Interbase database to MySql and I am having some trouble converting triggers. This is what I came so far, but can't seem to understand what are the errors in the following triggers. Can you help fix the syntax?

```
DELIMITER ^
```

In these 2 cases it says `into new.FinancialCode` is incorrect. What is the correct form to accomplish this? (**Lookup a value in a table and change it in the updated row**)

```
Create Trigger triggerFinancialCode  BEFORE UPDATE ON  FLOW
FOR EACH ROW
begin
  Select FinancialCode FROM Accounts where AccountCode = new.AccountCode 
  into new.FinancialCode ;
end ^

Create Trigger triggerFinancialCodePredicted  BEFORE UPDATE ON  PREDICTED_FLOW
FOR EACH ROW
begin
  Select FinancialCode FROM Accounts where AccountCode = new.AccountCode 
  into new.FinancialCode ;
end ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code -

```
CREATE TRIGGER triggerFinancialCode BEFORE UPDATE ON FLOW
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET @var = NULL;

  SELECT FinancialCode INTO @var FROM Accounts WHERE AccountCode = NEW.AccountCode;

  SET NEW.FinancialCode = @var;
END
```

Do the same for second trigger.